# Correct usage of stash\unstash into a different directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

In one of my stages I need to copy the contents of two folders after a build is completed and copy to a different directory.

I am actually converting a freestyle job to pipeline, and have been using the artifact deployer plugin. Reading around, it looks like stash and unstash commands should help with what I want to achieve.

Can someone verify if this is the correct approach below please?

```groovy
stage('Build') {
      steps {
        sh '''
          gulp set-staging-node-env
          gulp prepare-staging-files
          gulp webpack
        '''
        stash includes: '/dist/**/*', name: 'builtSources'
        stash includes: '/config/**/*', name: 'appConfig'
        dir('/some-dir') {
          unstash 'builtSources'
          unstash 'appConfig'
        }
      }
    }
```

If I change dir in one stage, does that mean all other stages thereafter will try to execute commands from that directory, or do they do back to using the workspace default location?

Thanks

**EDIT**

I have realised what I actually want to do is to copy built sources to a different node (running a different OS). So in my snippet I have shared, where I am switching directories, that directory is actually to be on a different machine (node) that I have setup.

Would I need to wrap the `dir()` block with a `node('my-node-name')` block? Im struggling to find examples.

Thanks

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I hope it is meant to be this:

```groovy
stash includes: 'dist/**/*', name: 'builtSources'

stash includes: 'config/**/*', name: 'appConfig'
```

where dist and config are the directories in the workspace path, so it should be a relative path like above.

Rest seems alright, only to mention that path "/some-dir" should be writable by jenkins user (user used to run jenkins daemon).

And yes it falls back to its then enclosing workspace path (in this case default) when it exits dir block.

**EDIT**

So when you stash a path, it is available to be unstashed at any step later in the pipeline. So yes, you could put `dir` block under a `node('<nodename>')` block.

You could add something like this :

```groovy
stage('Move the Build'){
  node('datahouse'){
    dir('/opt/jenkins_artifacts'){
      unstash 'builtSources'
      unstash 'appConfig'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you stash files on a relative path? I use includes: '../../../.gradle/**' for example, and I get "no files included in stash' and I know they're there

Comment: @ChrisF that's because it keeps the folder structure