# unable to stash files in jenkins pipeline - unclear Error: 0 files stashed

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am working on a jenkins pipeline, and there's a file that I want to stash and then unstash later in the build in order to use it.

The stash was working fine, until I made some changes in my pipeline, now I am getting 0 files stashed without any info.

```
stash allowEmpty: true, includes: '${myDir}/target/zippedjars.zip' , name: 'myJar'
```

This is how I am stashing, and note that it was working fine
and before I am running the stash comment I made sure that the zip exists !

Comment: Please include a sequence of the code that is not working. Are you stashing on one agent and un-stashing on another ? see if this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050248/correct-usage-of-stash-unstash-into-a-different-directory

Comment: thank you, I figured it out, when I replaced myDir with its value, the stash worked fine.
note that the problem was with stashing (i was getting 0 files stashed).

Fix:
```
Stash allowEmpty: true, includes: 'path/to/myDir/target/zippedjars.zip' , name: 'myJar'
```